# Custom Silverlight Splash Screen causes White Screen of Death

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight

I'm developing a Silverlight 4 application and I've created a custom splash screen.  At first glance, the custom splash screen worked well - really well.  After a few days I started noticing that the splash screen would no longer show and the screen would remain blank.  This seems to only occur when I open multiple IE tabs/windows all pointing to this same application.  The first few will load fine, while the following tabs/windows will remain "white" - as if nothing has/is loaded.  This doesn't appear to be an issue with other browsers that I've tested with (i.e., Firefox and Chrome).  Unfortunately, this product requires multiple screens to be open (and I'm not going to require our users to use a non-Microsoft internet browser).  Furthermore, we have another product that hosts this Silverlight application inside a WPF WebBrowser control (which is similar to IE - and experiences the same issues as delineated above).  Does anyone have any ideas on how to get around this?  This is becoming increasingly frustrating.

I should also point out, that the default splash screen seems to avoid these issues.  When I remove the custom splash screen, we no longer see these problems.

ANY help would be appreciated greatly!

-Tom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First diagnostic would be to use a really simple static custom splash, say a simple red rectangle.  If that works ok, does you custom splash use other resources from your web site such as images?   If so be sure that the cache properly.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this too. Our site still has IE7 Compatibility mode on and I am using IE9. When I use the developer toolbar and change the Document mode to IE9, I can't get it to happen again. It also works fine if the Browser Mode is set to IE7 or IE8 and IE7 compatibility.

I'm going to not use Splash Screens until we move to removing the IE7 compatibility mode, which is a task we have scheduled for the future.

EDIT: It turns out that compatibility mode may not have been the complete answer. I found [this forum post](http://forums.silverlight.net/p/138003/332140.aspx) that suggests putting the splash screen inline. This seems to be working 100%. I used a UserControl in ASP.Net to insert it. They also have a link to a [Microsoft Connect bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/550303/custom-splashscreen-not-always-showing-up) which has been closed as not reproducible. Maybe some more votes would get them to re-open it?